# Google Api Nearby Places on change of type, layer removed, but advertising stays, how can I remove the complete layer without reloading the page

Tags: google-maps, google-nearby

I have custom code to create a nearby search of places on google map.
Each search type creates a new layer, removed when selecting a different search type, my problem is, even thought he layer is removed, here in Thailand we have "Google partners advertising" show dependant on the search type and this "Layer" doesnt get removed, but added to when creating a new search layer.

This is the code I use to create the search (in part):
Creating a layer (Google):

```
<div id="map_layers_google">
    <input type="checkbox" name="map_google" id="map_google_restaurant" class="box" onclick="Propertywise.Maps.getDataWithinBounds('google_restaurant');" value="google_restaurant">
</div>

getDataWithinBounds: function(layer_name, except_this_area) {
    if (!Propertywise.Design.is_ie8_or_less) {
        this.layers_on_map[layer_name] = true;
            this.getEntitiesWithinBounds(layer_name);
}

getEntitiesWithinBounds: function(entity_name) {
    var $this = this;
    if (!this.getBounds()) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.getEntitiesWithinBounds(entity_name);
        }, 20);
    } else {
        var layer_name, category;
        var $this_input_el = jQuery("#map_" + entity_name);
        jQuery("#map_updating").fadeIn('fast');
        if (entity_name.indexOf('google') != -1) {
            layer_name = "google";
            category = entity_name.replace("google_", "");
        } else if (entity_name.indexOf('school') != -1) {
            layer_name = "schools";
            category = entity_name.replace("schools_", "");
        } else if (entity_name.indexOf('events') != -1) {
            layer_name = "events";
            category = entity_name.replace("events_", "");
        } else {
            layer_name = "transport";
            this.toggleTransitLayer();
        }
        jQuery("#map_layers_" + layer_name + " input").each(function(index, value) {
            var el_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var el_entity_name = el_id.replace("map_", "");
            Propertywise.Maps.layers_on_map[el_entity_name] = false;
            if (jQuery(this).is(":checked") && el_entity_name != entity_name) {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked", false);
            }
            if (jQuery(this).is(":checked") && el_entity_name == entity_name) {
                Propertywise.Maps.layers_on_map[entity_name] = true;
            }
        });
        if (jQuery("#map_" + entity_name).is(':checked') || Propertywise.this_page == "school") {
            if (layer_name == "google") {
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                Propertywise.Maps.removeMarkers(layer_name);
                var request = {
                    bounds: Propertywise.Maps.map.getBounds(),
                    types: [category]
                };
                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(Propertywise.Maps.map);
                service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
                    jQuery("#map_updating").fadeOut('fast');
                    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
                        Propertywise.Maps.createMarker(result.geometry.location.lat(), result.geometry.location.lng(), {
                            place: result,
                            type: category
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            this.removeMarkers(layer_name);
            jQuery("#map_updating").fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the setup and remove each layer:

```
setUpLayers: function() {
    var $this = this;
    jQuery.each(this.layers, function(layer_name, value) {
        Propertywise.Ajax.requests[layer_name] = [];
        $this.layers[layer_name] = [];
    });
},
removeMarkers: function(layer_name) {
    if (Propertywise.Maps.map) {
        var layer = this.layers[layer_name];
        for (var i = 0; i < layer.length; i++) {
            layer[i].setMap(null);
        }
        layer = [];
    }
}
```

Here is link to screen shot of the problem.
[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3hMpPUn6pT9a3ZsNUkyVXoyekk)

Question is, can anyone help with either changing the above to remove the complete layer(not just marker layer) or advise how to remove the advertising.. I understand this is part of terms of Google to display, but its unprofessional and looks terrible.

Best

Malisa

Comment: try to use a single `service`-instance for all layers

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Dr, but I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Each time I made a new search, I was requesting a NEW service.
Moving the following to the Map init, making the service global to the map worked.

       
`service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(Propertywise.Maps.map);`